# How can I add the columns that I have marked as bold and get the result in total time or in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Date          Event   eventid     username       starttime     Endtime   Remark   Totaltime
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05/30/2012  Break Out   0      Premnath Nair    **13:06:06**   13:06:06     NULL  00:00:00
05/30/2012  Break In    1      Premnath Nair    **13:22:24**   13:22:24     NULL  00:00:00
05/30/2012   NULL   255    Premnath Nair       08:54:49    19:21:02   normal  10:26:13
05/31/2012   NULL   255    Premnath Nair       07:52:55    18:50:45   normal  10:57:50
06/01/2012   NULL   NULL       NULL          NULL       NULL        NULL
06/02/2012   NULL   NULL        NULL         NULL       NULL        NULL
06/03/2012  Break Out   0      Premnath Nair       13:32:55 13:32:55    NULL  00:00:00
06/03/2012  Break In    1      Premnath Nair       13:43:11 13:43:11    NULL  00:00:00
06/03/2012  Out Duty    2   Premnath Nair   12:03:52    12:03:52    NULL  00:00:00
```

This is the data from the database

I have got the total time by this query

```
convert (varchar(8), convert(datetime, endtime, 8) - convert(datetime, starttime, 8), 108)  as totaltime
```

Need to know how can I get the total break time need to add the break in time and the break out time

Comment: mysql is not sql server.

Answer (score 0):

using :

```
select datediff(minute,'11:11:11 PM','11:15:13 PM')
```

Comment: Sir the both the times are in different coloum and its not only one data need to do for the whole data thanks pls let me know if u have a solution for the query